# Retrive json data from post Method and append to array

Tags: json, swift, post

I trying to retrive data from **post** method URL and here's my code

```
    let url = NSURL(string:"http://urlwithpostmethod.com")

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

    values = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray





    for dataObject : AnyObject in values
    {
        if let data = dataObject as? NSDictionary
        {

            self.ids.append(data["id"] as! Int)
            self.titles.append(data["name_en"] as! String)
            self.descs.append(data["discription_en"] as! String)
            self.images.append(data["image"] as! String)









        }
    }
```

But when i run application crash :( and not retrieving data from the url and get error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

any suggestion how to retrieve data from POST method URL ?

and this my json return from url

```
[
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name_ar": "زيوت التروس",
    "name_en": "Gear Oils",
    "discription_ar": "GEAR OILS - BEST FOR EXTENDING GEARS LIFETIME",
    "discription_en": "GEAR OILS - BEST FOR EXTENDING GEARS LIFETIME",
    "image": "uploads/category/1466952382_3ed3d-gear_oils.png",
    "sort": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "created_at": "2016-06-26 14:16:39",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-26 14:46:22"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name_ar": "Passenger Vehicles Motor Oil",
    "name_en": "Passenger Vehicles Motor Oil",
    "discription_ar": "PASSENGER VEHICLES MOTOR OIL - EXCELLENT PERFORMANCE FOR YOUR PASSENGER VEHICLE",
    "discription_en": "PASSENGER VEHICLES MOTOR OIL - EXCELLENT PERFORMANCE FOR YOUR PASSENGER VEHICLE",
    "image": "uploads/category/1466952496_6b90d-passenger_vehicles.png",
    "sort": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "created_at": "2016-06-26 14:48:16",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-26 14:48:16"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "name_ar": "Industrial Lubricants",
    "name_en": "Industrial Lubricants",
    "discription_ar": "INDUSTRIAL LUBRICANTS - EXCELLENT PERFORMANCE FOR SPECIFIC TECHNICAL APPLICATIONS",
    "discription_en": "INDUSTRIAL LUBRICANTS - EXCELLENT PERFORMANCE FOR SPECIFIC TECHNICAL APPLICATIONS",
    "image": "uploads/category/1466952588_c554d-pro.png",
    "sort": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "created_at": "2016-06-26 14:49:48",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-26 14:49:48"
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "name_ar": "Coolant water",
    "name_en": "Coolant water",
    "discription_ar": "Test",
    "discription_en": "Test",
    "image": "uploads/category/1466973030_image.png",
    "sort": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "created_at": "2016-06-26 20:30:30",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-26 20:30:30"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your URL in the post method file have anything appended to it? For instance, something like:

```
local URL = "http://www.location_of_json.com/json.php?userid="..mime.b64(userid).."&password="..mime.b64(password);
```

Perhaps the data isn't being sent to the json file?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken (and I could be, i'm no expert) you would need to pass the needed data through that URL over to the json file.

Comment: i updated my question and posted hwo the data return from the URL

Comment: and then of course, the json would do what it needs to do with it

Comment: when i tried it with GET method it's working but not working with POST

Comment: Are you passing anything as a string from the post?

Comment: Nope nothing passed

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using forced unwrapping `as!` as much as possible in general, but especially when parsing backend data. This is a guaranteed way to crash your app.
Instead, aways treat those values as optionals, unwrap them conditionally and deal with the data respectively.